# Manual login in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my login function

```
    public function login(Request $request) {



    $username=$request::get('username');
    $email=$request::get('email');
    $password=$request::get('password');

    $user=users::where('username', $username , 'email', $email , 'password' ,$password);
    if($user){
        echo 'authenticated';
    }
    else{
        echo 'not authenticated';
    }
}
```

When a login to the application. After entering wrong credential it lead's me to if condition not else. 
Any other logic or idea should be appreciable 
Thanks

Comment: what you want exactly you are asking that another way to throw the messages??

Comment: you should use built in auth and override the login method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use built in authentication and override the methods to implement your logic.

and as per your question change these lines to the followings

```
$user=users::where('username', $username, 'email', $email, 'password' ,$password)->first();
if (!is_null($user)) {
    echo 'authenticated';
}
else{
    echo 'not authenticated';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A database query always has to end in [`->all()`, `->get()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#retrieving-models), [`->count()` or `->first()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) to execute it. at the moment you are comparing a query builder object, wich will always be true because it has a value.

Also, it is not safe to just put the variable in your if without any condition.

Your function should look more like this:

```
public function login(Request $request) {
    $username = $request::get('username');
    $email = $request::get('email');
    $password = $request::get('password');

    $user = users::where(['username' => $username, 'email' => $email, 'password' => $password])->count();
    if ($user > 0) {
        echo 'authenticated';
    }
    else {
        echo 'not authenticated';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question has has a correct answer marked, however in some ways it isn't based on the security of the answer..

I have to make a serious point, that you should **ALWAYS** be encrypting every users password!! By the looks of your query, you are storing them in plain string, this is a big no no and anyone who uses your site would not appreciate that.

To register:

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $username = $request->username;
    $password = $request->password;
    $email = $request->email;

    $user = new User;
    $user->username = $username;
    $user->email = $email;
    $user->password = Hash::make($password);
    $user->save();
    // redirect to the login page
}
```

To login:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $username = $request->username;
    $password = $request->password;
    $email = $request->email;
    if(Auth::attempt(['username' => $username, 'email => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
        echo 'authenticated';
    } else {
        echo 'not authenticated';
    }
}
```

The Auth::attempt() method automatically encrypts the users input password value and checks against that.

Have a serious read of the Laravel docs here to do manual authentication: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#authenticating-users

Answer (score 1):

yoy can use the authethicate function instead 
Check the following code

```html
use Auth;
public function login(Request $request){
    $username = $request->get('username');
    $password = $request->get('password');
    if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $username, 'password' => $password])) {
      return "User authentciated";
    }else{
      return "Invalid user";
    }
 }
```